# Rails selecting objects with conditions on associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have Author(authors table) and has_many books. Class Book (books table). How can i select authors that have at-least 1 book effectively. Currently am using.

`@authors = Author.where(:active => true).select { |author| author.books.count > 0 }`

It is working well but it runs many queries. How can i do it in a more effective way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with sql:

```
 Author.where(:active => true).joins(:books).group("author_id HAVING count(books.id) > 0")
```

Comment: Thanks it works, though in my case i had to change .group("author.id ....") to .group("author_id ....") and the statement was like:

Author.where(:active => true).joins(:books).group("author_id HAVING count(books.id) > 0")

Answer (score 1):

```
Author.where(:active => true).joins(:books).group(:id).having("count(books.id) > 0")
```

More better way